# what is a word for "narrow-mindedness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a specific word to describe **a person with a narrow perspective**, suggesting a lack of foresight/consideration of the broader implications of their decisions.

This would preferably be the noun-equivalent of "myopic," as in:

*I am most concerned with the politician's "myopic-ness" and total disregard for the broader implications of his policy proposal.*

Comment: myopia would be the noun form of myopic. And yes it's also used metaphorically as myopic is.

Comment: You could use "short-sightedness."  By "disregard," do you mean "indifference," a separate attribute from myopia? If not, if you mean "failure to see," "myopic disregard" might get the job done and save a few words.  Also, I associate "narrow perspective" with "tunnel vision," or maybe "parochialism." Is this pol primarily ignorant of consequences or does he only care that his constituents get what they want? The right wording depends on the precise message, and "narrow-minded" and "short-sighted" mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

There is the figurative expression **blinkered vision**, which alludes to the devices placed on horses that pull carriages to obstruct their peripheral vision.

> I wouldn't vote for  her. She has a blinkered outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **tunnel vision** is listed in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tunnel_vision) as meaning

> NOUN
> 1.1 *informal* The tendency to focus exclusively on a single or limited objective or view.
>
> *she has tunnel vision in all matters of opinion and morality*

So perhaps

> I am most concerned with the politician's **tunnel vision** and total disregard for the broader implications of his policy proposal.

Answer (score 0):

provincialism    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/provincialism)

> 1. narrowness of mind or outlook; lack of sophistication

As in:

She is so provincial in her platform, I cannot cast a vote for her.